# Ruby testing with RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Im trying to do some simple ruby (without rails) testing using  Rspec and Bundler. 
From the command line im running `$ bundle exec rspec spec/hello_example.rb`

Im getting no method errors pointing me towards my spec_helper.rb file like so:

```
 /Users/rockyboy/test-ruby/spec/spec/spec_helper.rb:31:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions=' for #<RSpec::Expectations::Configuration:0x007fa91115dee0> (NoMethodError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:580:in `expect_with'
    from /Users/rockyboy/test-ruby/spec/spec/spec_helper.rb:23:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core.rb:154:in `configure'
    from /Users/rockyboy/test-ruby/spec/spec/spec_helper.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1036:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1036:in `block in setup_load_path_and_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1036:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1036:in `setup_load_path_and_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1036:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1036:in `setup_load_path_and_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:25:in `configure'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:17:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:103:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'`
```

I have both Rpec version 2.99 and 3.2.3 installed on my computer. Bundler informs me it is using version 2.99. Im guessing I have to switch Bundler so that it uses Rspec version 3.2.3 instead. Can anyone please tell me how I can make  sure Bundler is running version 3.2.3. Or any other method of how I could solve this issue.  Thank you so much !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Gemfile](http://bundler.io/gemfile.html) in your project root:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem "rspec", '~> 3.2.3'
```

Comment: hello thank you for your answer. I have heard of this before i was also reading on the bundler website through you're link but im not entirely clear on how to create a gemfile. thank you so much

Comment: It is a plain text file named 'Gemfile' (no file extension) which is in your applications/scripts root directory. Open a simple text editor, create a new file with the content above and save it as plain text with the name 'Gemfile'.

Comment: thank you for the explanation . i did everything mentioned above and  Iam still getting the same error message

Comment: Did you place the Gemfile in the wrong folder? It needs to be in the same folder you are running `$ bundle exec rspec spec/hello_example.rb` from. From looking at your stack trace you have two nested spec folders: `/Users/rockyboy/test-ruby/spec/spec/`.

Comment: i have the gem file in my spec folder. which is where iam running '$ bundle exec rspec spec/hello_example.rb' from

Comment: Try running `$ bundle install`.

Comment: when i run bundle install its tell me  it is using rspec 2.99

Comment: can you please tell also tell me how i can add some code  to the comments for example  `code`  is not working thank you so much

Comment: im trying to add new  my error message but its saying its too long 
`